# javafx how to make a table cell editable dynamically?

Tags: javafx-2

I have a table view in which few columns are editable and few are non-editable.
When i keyin some value in first column and press tab , a service is called and the returned object is mapped to table row.
My requirement is to make the non-editable column as editable(only in the row where i have editied) based on a flag in returned object.
Below is the code for calling service and setting returned object to row.

```
colCtrNo.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<CtrRcptDlvryDTO, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<CtrRcptDlvryDTO, String> t) {
            CtrRcptDlvryDTO c = t.getTableView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if(c.getCtrNo() != null && !"".equals(c.getCtrNo())){

            c = GateIn.gatePassServiceRef.gateIn_validateRcptCtrFx(c, 1, 5090,null);  
            tblReceiptContent.set(t.getTablePosition().getRow(), c);
            }
        }
    });
```

Please suggest how to turn non-editable columns into editable based on a flag at runtime.

Comment: See custom cell factory usage of Oracle's tableview tutorial. As summary, you will be creating a TableCell having or not having a TextField according to the item row.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
 Col.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("Name"));
    Col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    Col.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<User, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<User, String> t) {
                ((User) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Hi Anshul, Issue is not about setting value in non-editable column but making it editable. For example consider i have 2 table columns colCtrNo,colCtrDesc.  on initial load of screen colCtrDesc is non-editable.When i edit colCtrNo  how can i make colCtrDesc based on value in colCtrNo? Because it was alredy created as non editable cell. u want me to create the same column again with a different cell factory?

Comment: sry @Sil i dont recognise what you want to tell...i try to sort out it and back you as i can